# Error when trying to import React-Gridstack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gridstack

When I try to import react-gridstack into my project, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined
./node_modules/react-gridstack/lib/grid-stack.js
```

This is where it found the error:

```
  257 | 
  258 | console.log(_react2.default.PropTypes);
  259 | GridStack.propTypes = {
> 260 |   acceptWidgets: _react2.default.PropTypes.bool,
  261 |   alwaysShowResizeHandle: _react2.default.PropTypes.bool,
  262 |   animate: _react2.default.PropTypes.bool,
  263 |   auto: _react2.default.PropTypes.bool,
```

I put a console.log in there to see the value of _react2.default.PropTypes, which returned undefined. How do I fix this error

Comment: react-gridstack is outdated, its last time update is 5 years ago

Comment: kk, ty for the info